# WCF Soap Service Randomly Failing

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I currently have a soap service that I am calling. It works around 90% of the time. However I cannot seem to pinpoint what is causing the issue. Thus making it difficult to fix since I cannot replicate the issue.

I am randomly getting the following error:

```
CAUTL001E Failed to load xml document from string [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Message>

  <Header>
    <ProtocolVersion>550</ProtocolVersion>
    <ProtocolInfo>3</ProtocolInfo>
  </Header>

  <Elements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
<faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
<faultstring xml:lang="en-US">
```

I am continually passing the exact same parameter set to the service, so the output *should* be the same. Pass or fail.

I cannot get the service to fail using the WCFTestClient. It is only failing when trying to access from an outside application.

The 2 applications that I have gotten the service to fail in are Powershell and vMWare orchestrator.

I can also confirm that it does not look like the issue lies within the service. The error checking that I have provided within the web service is never being reached, even when the application receives this error message.

I have searched for the last 2 weeks trying to get a better understanding of what the error message really means but have not been successful.

If it helps at all, here is a simplified view of what my web service looks like.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebMethod]
MyObj submitChange(string params);



public MyObj submitChange(string params)
{
    try
    {
        //does something with the params,..

        myObj response = new myObj(params);

        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Send an email to me containing exception details

        throw ex;
    }

}


[Serializable]
public class MyObj
{
    public string params { get; set; }

    public MyObj(string _params)
    {
        params = _params;
    }
}
```

Here is the powershell code that works 90% of the time:

```
$uri = 'http://linktomyservice/myservice.svc?wsdl'
$req = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri
$req.Timeout = 2000000
$response = $req.myFunc($params)
```

To provide a little bit more information:

- The service is hosted on a leveraged dev web box in my environment.
- I have seen the failures when running a local powershell script, as well as on a remote server in my environment.
- There is no proxy/firewall interference between the client and the service.
- There is no required authentication to

Comment: Clients nor services fail randomly, so it must be something in between. Explain your topology. Is there a proxy server or firewall of some sorts in between service and client?

Comment: There is no proxy or firewall between the service and the client. Not even credentials required. I am simply providing the vRO client/Powershell with the address to the service wsdl while supplying timeout information. I am denying any proxy configuration and authentication.

Comment: It was just a suggestion. Please explain what the setup _does_ look like. Are service and client on the same machine, same network, and so on.

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry to be so vague, I am not the most familiar in this area yet. And the topology does not appear (to me atleast) to be anything out of the ordinary.